# Tools for optimizing Shared LIbraries (.so) for ARM32 and ARM64

Tags: android, optimization, linux-kernel, shared-libraries

Is there any possibility to take .so and run it through tool which can optimize further that code for runtime?

Comment: nope... that'd require runtime transpilation, not that easy

Comment: I thought so. What about some tool to give hints which parts of program to optimize? I am writing Go Lang code and compiling it into .so

Comment: There is no magic tool that can tell you what and where to optimize. What you should do is profile your code at runtime and see the timings of the functions of your library to identify possible functions to optimize, bottlenecks etc. See e.g. this: https://go.dev/blog/pprof

Comment: Great idea, but problem is I execute this on Android phone...it is Go code compiled to shared library for arm32